# Segmentation Fault when running recursive binary search algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary-search

So I'm trying recursion for the first time, writing a simple binary search algorithm in Python 3. After running my program I was getting this error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
I did some research and it said to add this line: `sys.setrecursionlimit(40000)`

Which I did. When I enter a number that's not in my list I get this Segmentation Fault error. I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178892/segmentation-fault-for-deep-recursion-upon-going-from-python-2-6-to-2-7) From what I gather in Python deep recursion exhausts the memory?

I can't imagine deep recursion is not supported in Python? Anyways, here's my code:

```
import sys

arr = [5, 17, 23, 33, 39, 44, 58, 62, 70, 74, 82, 99]
end = len(arr)
sys.setrecursionlimit(40000)

def binarySearch(arr, start, end,  x):

   #print("This is end: {}".format(end))
    mid = int((end + start)/2)
    #print("This is start {}".format(start))
    #print("This is end {}".format(end))
    #print("This is mid {}".format(mid))

    if x == arr[mid]:
        return x
    elif (x < arr[mid]):
        start = 0
        end = mid - 1
        return binarySearch(arr, start, end, x)
    else: # if x > arr[mid]
        start = mid + 1
        end = end
        return binarySearch(arr, start, end,  x)


position = binarySearch(arr, 0, 12, 55)
print(position)
```

Comment: There is no way you'd need that many recursive calls using binary search. There's no array that big that can fit into memory.

Comment: I haven't gone over your code yet, but if you're getting a recursion error on a data structure this small, your algorithm is doing something wrong. (Generally getting a recursion error tells you you did something wrong, or your problem is not a recursive problem, and shouldn't have a recursive solution)

Comment: Your code makes no provision for `x` not being in `arr`. What would you expect it to return in that case?  (Also, you should probably be returning `mid` not `x`)

Comment: You have a few mistakes here. `start = 0` is one of them. Another is that you don't check for the base case `start > end`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will look into it.

Comment: _"I can't imagine deep recursion is not supported in Python?"_ - deep recursion is most certainly supported in Python, but _infinite_ memory is not. Even if you set the maximum recursion level to a large number, the interpreter can still run out of memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in your code:

1. You don't have a base case. You're supposed to check whether `start > end` before going through with the recursion.
2. `start = 0` really should be `start = start`, or don't add it at all.

Fixing these bugs, and cleaning up your code a bit, this works -

```
def binarySearch(arr, start, end, x):
    if start <= end:
        mid = (end + start) // 2

        if x == arr[mid]:
            return mid
        elif x < arr[mid]:
            end = mid - 1           
        else:
            start = mid + 1

        return binarySearch(arr, start, end, x)

    return -1
```

```
binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr), 55)
-1

binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr), 58)
6
```

Also, note that, for a `O(logN)` algorithm, you'll *never* need a maximum recursion depth of 40,000. If you're running into a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error, you should re-evaluate your algorithm first.

Comment: @ChristianDean Thank you, you too. This week has been a bit busy for me :)

Comment: @newcoder Welcome! Always remember to check your base case(s) when writing recursive routines.